# Filling a vector in order using threads in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector

I'm attempting to fill a huge double vector (1929x1341, might even get bigger) with data, which right now takes around 10 seconds to do.

for reference, this is the code so far:

```
vector<vector<float>> vector1;
for (int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++) {
    vector<float> vector2;
    for (int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++) {
        int someNumber = calculateNumber(x,y);
        vector2.push_back(someNumber);
    }
    vector1.push_back(vector2);
}
```

I'm thinking I should be able to cut down on the work-time by dividing the work over separate threads. Specifically I could separate the second for-loop into each their own thread.

Unfortunately, I am not good with threads. The main issue is that the vectors needs to be filled in order. So I can't just separate the second vector to their own threads and combine them later, as that would put them into a semi-random order. I've looked into mutex and Condition Variables, but I am not able to find a good solution to this specific problem.

Would anyone be willing to help me out here?

Comment: You combine them in the same order that you dispatch them to other threads in, not as they finish.

Comment: 'So I can't just separate the second vector to their own threads and combine them later' - yes, you can. Just give the thread an index (or reference) where in the first vector it can put it's results to.

Comment: It would be worth using `std::vector::reserve` to reserve the memory

Comment: what's the bottleneck currently? the memory bandwidth or the cpu?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath certainly the cpu.

Comment: @lorro I'm trying to tell the thread where exactly in the vector they should put the results, however that seems problematic. It crashes due to "vector subscript out of range", even with reserving memory. Resizing works though. Is that the way to go?

Comment: @Galik: since we don't know the finish order of the threads, `reserve` won't help.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath reserve will help for the individual vectors if not for the vector of vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do something like:

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> vector1(mapWidth);
std::vector<std::thread> threads;

for (int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++) {
    threads.emplace_back([&, x]() {
        for (int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++) {
            int someNumber = calculateNumber(x, y);
            vector1[x].push_back(someNumber);
        }
    });
}

for (int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++) {
    threads[x].join();
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks a bunch. The work-time seems to have dropped from around 10 seconds to 2 :D

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part here is having a few threads all working at the same time. When one of the threads becomes free another one takes over to create a new vector.

For this [std::future](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) is useful because it allows us to synchronize the collection of results shared between threads. We can start one *asynchronous* task for each thread and collects its results in a [std::future](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) object.

For this I used [std::async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) to create the threads:

```
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

int width = 5;
int height = 3;

float calculateNumber(int x, int y)
{
    return x * y;
}

std::vector<float> fill_info(int x, int height)
{
    std::vector<float> v;
    v.reserve(height);

    for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
        v.push_back(calculateNumber(x, y));

    return v;
}

int main()
{
    // our thread limit
    const auto number_of_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

    // our data container
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> v;

    // queue of asynchronous (shared) results
    std::queue<std::future<std::vector<float>>> q;

    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        if(q.size() >= number_of_threads)
        {
            v.push_back(q.front().get()); // blocks until thread is done
            q.pop();
        }

        q.emplace(std::async(std::launch::async, fill_info, x, height));
    }

    // collect uncollected results
    while(!q.empty())
    {
        v.push_back(q.front().get()); // blocks until thread is done
        q.pop();
    }

    std::cout << v.size()<< '\n';

    for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
        for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
            std::cout << "{" << x << ", " << y << "}: " << v[x][y] << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
{0, 0}: 0
{0, 1}: 0
{0, 2}: 0
{1, 0}: 0
{1, 1}: 1
{1, 2}: 2
{2, 0}: 0
{2, 1}: 2
{2, 2}: 4
{3, 0}: 0
{3, 1}: 3
{3, 2}: 6
{4, 0}: 0
{4, 1}: 4
{4, 2}: 8
```

Comment: That is quite a bit more complicated solution. Would it decrease the work time drastically by reusing threads as opposed to creating a new one for every vector?

Comment: @Excludos creating a thread and starting it is much more expensive than waiting on an event. that being said, there's always a large enough workload (per thread) to make the difference become negligible.

Comment: @Excludos This solution does create a new thread for every vector it just makes sure you never have more than a few threads running at the same time. That *can* be more efficient than having lots of threads competing for the same CPU. But if a simpler solution is working for you then go with that. Without a special library re-using threads would be more complicated still.